# multine line array in table cell

Tags: tables, align, arrays

```
\begin{table} 
\centering 
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.3}
\begin{tabular}{c | l}
Group element & $\begin{array} {r@{}l@{}} U(\xi) & {}= e^{\xi^a P_a} \\ U(\Lambda) & {}= e^{-\frac{1}{2}\lambda^{ab}M_{ab}} \end{array}$ \\ 
\hline 
Algebra & $\begin{array} {r@{}l@{}} [M_{[ab]},M_{[cd]}] & {}= 4\eta_{[a[c}M_{d]b]} \\ f_{[ab][cd]}{}^{[ef]} & {}= 8 \eta_{[c[b}\delta^{[e}_{a]}\delta^{f]}_{d]} \\ P_{a},M_{[bc]} & {}= 2\eta_{a[b}P_{c]} \\ f_{a,[bc]}{}^d & {}= 2 \eta_{a[b}\delta_{c]}^d\end{array}$ \\  \hline 
Connection & $A_\mu = A_\mu{}^a T_a$  \\  \hline 
Curvature & $\begin{array} {r@{}l@{}} R_{\mu\nu} & {}= R_{\mu\nu}{}^a T_a \\ R_{\mu\nu}{}^a & {}= 2 \partial_{[\mu}A_{\nu]} + f_{ab}{}^c A_\mu{}^b A_\nu{}^c \end{array}$ \\
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

[image]

I am trying to get a lie bracket on the 3rd line of the $[P_{a},M_{[bc]}]$ in the algebra row. Whenever I add [ and ] to the left and right, I get

[image]

with the following errors

[image]

Comment: `\\ ` takes an optional argument, which is a length. You can use `\\\relax [ P_{a},M_{[bc]} ]` for instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\\` takes an optional argument, which is a length. You can use `\\\relax [ P_{a},M_{[bc]} ]`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\begin{table} 
\centering 
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.3}
\begin{tabular}{c | l}
Group element & $\begin{array} {r@{}l@{}} U(\xi) & {}= e^{\xi^a P_a} \\ U(\Lambda) & {}= e^{-\frac{1}{2}\lambda^{ab}M_{ab}} \end{array}$ \\ 
\hline 
Algebra & $\begin{array} {r@{}l@{}} [M_{[ab]},M_{[cd]}] & {}=
4\eta_{[a[c}M_{d]b]} \\ f_{[ab][cd]}{}^{[ef]} & {}= 8
\eta_{[c[b}\delta^{[e}_{a]}\delta^{f]}_{d]} \\\relax [ P_{a},M_{[bc]} ]& {}= 2\eta_{a[b}P_{c]} \\ f_{a,[bc]}{}^d & {}= 2 \eta_{a[b}\delta_{c]}^d\end{array}$ \\  \hline 
Connection & $A_\mu = A_\mu{}^a T_a$  \\  \hline 
Curvature & $\begin{array} {r@{}l@{}} R_{\mu\nu} & {}= R_{\mu\nu}{}^a T_a \\ R_{\mu\nu}{}^a & {}= 2 \partial_{[\mu}A_{\nu]} + f_{ab}{}^c A_\mu{}^b A_\nu{}^c \end{array}$ \\
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

But I would use `aligned` instead of the hand made arrays, and probably a few other things.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{eqparbox}
\newcommand\MyLeftColumn[1]{\eqmakebox[A][r]{$#1$}}
\begin{document}
\begin{table} 
\centering 
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.3}
\begin{tabular}{l  l}
\toprule
Group element & $\begin{aligned} \MyLeftColumn{U(\xi)} &= e^{\xi^a P_a} \\ 
\MyLeftColumn{U(\Lambda)} & {}=
e^{-\frac{1}{2}\lambda^{ab}M_{ab}} \end{aligned}$ \\ 
\midrule
Algebra & $\begin{aligned}\relax \MyLeftColumn{[M_{[ab]},M_{[cd]}]} & =
4\eta_{[a[c}M_{d]b]} \\ \MyLeftColumn{f_{[ab][cd]}{}^{[ef]}} & = 8
\eta_{[c[b}\delta^{[e}_{a]}\delta^{f]}_{d]} \\\relax 
\MyLeftColumn{[ P_{a},M_{[bc]} ]}& = 2\eta_{a[b}P_{c]} \\ 
\MyLeftColumn{f_{a,[bc]}{}^d} & {}= 2 \eta_{a[b}\delta_{c]}^d\end{aligned}$ \\  
\midrule
Connection & $\MyLeftColumn{A_\mu} = A_\mu{}^a T_a$  \\  
\midrule
Curvature & $\begin{aligned} \MyLeftColumn{R_{\mu\nu}} & = R_{\mu\nu}{}^a T_a \\
\MyLeftColumn{R_{\mu\nu}{}^a} & = 2 \partial_{[\mu}A_{\nu]} + f_{ab}{}^c A_\mu{}^b A_\nu{}^c \end{aligned}$ \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, thank you. Can you adress adding vertical lines via {| l | l |} in the table? As I use them with this example, the lines don't quite allign like in a normal table

Comment: @LopeyTall There is a trend of having less vertical lines. The tools from the`booktabs` package do not work with vertical lines. However, I personally would not want to add them here either.

Answer (score 3):

I have edited this answer because, with the lastest version of `nicematrix` (v. 5.1), there is no need to use Tikz to draw the vertical rule: the symbole `|` in the preamble is directly compatible with the rules of `booktabs`.

---

If you want to add vertical rules in a tabular constructed with the tools of `booktabs` (which is not the spirit of `booktabs`), you may use `nicematrix`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{eqparbox}
\newcommand\MyLeftColumn[1]{\eqmakebox[A][r]{$#1$}}
\begin{document}
\begin{table} 
\centering 
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.3}
\begin{NiceTabular}{l|l}
\toprule
Group element & $\begin{aligned} \MyLeftColumn{U(\xi)} &= e^{\xi^a P_a} \\ 
\MyLeftColumn{U(\Lambda)} & {}=
e^{-\frac{1}{2}\lambda^{ab}M_{ab}} \end{aligned}$ \\ 
\midrule
Algebra & $\begin{aligned}\relax \MyLeftColumn{[M_{[ab]},M_{[cd]}]} & =
4\eta_{[a[c}M_{d]b]} \\ \MyLeftColumn{f_{[ab][cd]}{}^{[ef]}} & = 8
\eta_{[c[b}\delta^{[e}_{a]}\delta^{f]}_{d]} \\\relax 
\MyLeftColumn{[ P_{a},M_{[bc]} ]}& = 2\eta_{a[b}P_{c]} \\ 
\MyLeftColumn{f_{a,[bc]}{}^d} & {}= 2 \eta_{a[b}\delta_{c]}^d\end{aligned}$ \\  
\midrule
Connection & $\MyLeftColumn{A_\mu} = A_\mu{}^a T_a$  \\  
\midrule
Curvature & $\begin{aligned} \MyLeftColumn{R_{\mu\nu}} & = R_{\mu\nu}{}^a T_a \\
\MyLeftColumn{R_{\mu\nu}{}^a} & = 2 \partial_{[\mu}A_{\nu]} + f_{ab}{}^c A_\mu{}^b A_\nu{}^c \end{aligned}$ \\
\bottomrule
\end{NiceTabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image: Result of the above code]