# booktabs table column seperation

Tags: tables, beamer, booktabs

Struggling with fitting a table on a beamer slide.

[image]

Why is there so much spave between columns?!

```
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Recovering GR}
\begin{table} 
\centering 
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.3}
\begin{tabular}{ l l}
\midrule
\makecell[l]{Dependent spin \\connection} & $\MyLeftColumn{\omega_\mu{}^{ab}} = 2 e^{\lambda[a} \partial_{[\lambda}e_{\mu]}{}^{b]} - e_{\mu}{}^c e^{\rho a} e^{\sigma b} \partial_{[\rho} e_{\sigma]c}$ \\ 
\midrule 
Metric & $\MyLeftColumn{g_{\mu\nu} } = e_{\mu}{}^a e_\nu{}^b \eta_{ab}$ \\  
\midrule
\makecell[l]{Christoffel \\ connection} & $\MyLeftColumn{\Gamma^\nu_{\mu\lambda}} = e^\nu{}_a ( \partial_\mu e_\lambda{}^a  + \omega_\mu{}^a{}_b e_\lambda{}^a)$   \\  
\midrule 
Zero torsion & $\begin{aligned} \MyLeftColumn{T_{\mu\lambda}{}^\nu} &= 2 \Gamma_{[\mu\lambda]}^\nu \\ &= 2 e^\nu{}_a ( \partial_{[\mu} e_{\lambda]}{}^a  + \omega_{[\mu}{}^a{}_b e_{\lambda]}{}^a = R_{\mu\lambda}{}^a(e)=0) \\ &= 0 \end{aligned}$ \\
\midrule
On-shell & $\MyLeftColumn{R_{\mu\nu}} = e^\mu{}_a R_{\mu\nu}{}^{ab}(\omega) = 0$ \\  
\midrule
Action & $\begin{aligned}\MyLeftColumn{S} &= \int d^4x \text{det}(e_\mu{}^a) R(\omega)\\ \MyLeftColumn{R(\omega)} &= e^\mu{}^a e^\mu{}_b R_{\mu\nu}{}^{ab}(\omega)
\end{aligned}$ \\  
\midrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{frame}
```

my preamble

```
\documentclass[notes]{beamer}
\usetheme{Singapore}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath,tabu}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{eqparbox}
\newcommand\MyLeftColumn[1]{\eqmakebox[A][r]{$#1$}}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{subcaption} 
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage[czech]{babel}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amssymb,graphicx}
\usepackage{hyphenat}
\usepackage[font={small}]{caption}
\usepackage{float}
```

I am using this table formatting after Schrodinger's cat's answer here [multine line array in table cell](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/548157/multine-line-array-in-table-cell/548161?noredirect=1#comment1384821_548161)

Comment: I do not reproduce the output. Do you use `\MyLeftColumn` somewhere else in the document? If so, you need to modify it. The `A` in `\eqmakebox[A][r]{$#1$}` is an identifier, all boxes produced with this identifier will have the same width. So you might need `\newcommand\MyLeftColumn[1]{\eqmakebox[\myID][r]{$#1$}}, and so on. Also note that `tabu` is not necessarily the most recommended package, and `graphicx` gets loaded by `beamer`.
\newcommand{\myID}{A}` and when you do the second table e.g. `\renewcommand{\myID}{B}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I understand what is going wrong, even though from the codes you post this does not necessarily follow. I believe you are using the `\eqmakebox` command with the same tag/id somewhere else in the document. This will make all the boxes have the maximal widths of all these contents. However, you want only to maximize the widths of the boxes in a give table. This can be achieved by giving them a unique id per table. The following code provides one possible way of accomplishing this.

```
\documentclass[notes]{beamer}
\usetheme{Singapore}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{eqparbox}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{subcaption} 
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage[czech]{babel}
\newcommand{\diff}{\mathop{}\!\mathsf{d}}
\newcommand\MyLeftColumn[1]{\eqmakebox[\myID][r]{$#1$}}
\newcommand{\myID}{A}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Recovering GR}
\begin{table} 
\centering 
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.3}%
\renewcommand{\myID}{RGR}% <- use a new id for the eqparboxes in this frame
\small
\begin{tabular}{ l l}
\midrule
\makecell[l]{Dependent spin \\connection} & $\MyLeftColumn{\omega_\mu{}^{ab}} = 2 e^{\lambda[a} \partial_{[\lambda}e_{\mu]}{}^{b]} - e_{\mu}{}^c e^{\rho a} e^{\sigma b} \partial_{[\rho} e_{\sigma]c}$ \\ 
\midrule 
Metric & $\MyLeftColumn{g_{\mu\nu} } = e_{\mu}{}^a e_\nu{}^b \eta_{ab}$ \\  
\midrule
\makecell[l]{Christoffel \\ connection} & $\MyLeftColumn{\Gamma^\nu_{\mu\lambda}} = e^\nu{}_a ( \partial_\mu e_\lambda{}^a  + \omega_\mu{}^a{}_b e_\lambda{}^a)$   \\  
\midrule 
Zero torsion & $\begin{aligned} \MyLeftColumn{T_{\mu\lambda}{}^\nu} &= 2 \Gamma_{[\mu\lambda]}^\nu \\ &= 2 e^\nu{}_a ( \partial_{[\mu} e_{\lambda]}{}^a  + \omega_{[\mu}{}^a{}_b e_{\lambda]}{}^a = R_{\mu\lambda}{}^a(e)=0) \\ &= 0 \end{aligned}$ \\
\midrule
On-shell & $\MyLeftColumn{R_{\mu\nu}} = e^\mu{}_a R_{\mu\nu}{}^{ab}(\omega) = 0$ \\  
\midrule
Action & $\begin{aligned}\MyLeftColumn{S} &= \int\!\diff^4x\, \det(e_\mu{}^a) R(\omega)\\ \MyLeftColumn{R(\omega)} &= e^\mu{}^a e^\mu{}_b R_{\mu\nu}{}^{ab}(\omega)
\end{aligned}$ \\  
\midrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you have further tables in which you use `\MyLeftColumn`, use `\renewcommand{\myID}{...}` where `...` is unique per table. (One could make this automatic by adding some counters or make this depend on some counter, but this will never be completely fail safe, so I recommend the more manual way here.)

BTW, use `\det` instead of `\text{det}`, and a differential `d` that is distinguishable from a variable `d`.

Comment: Thank you so much, I was totally unaware to my other definitions earlier in the document effecting things! Cheers! :D :)